# Animated Image not show in latest version of Chrome

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, animated-gif

I am using chrome `Version 27.0.1453.94 m`.  I have an animated `.gif` image on my webpage. The [url](http://www.hrgp.biz/Images/ajax-loader.gif) showing image in firefox and IE but not showing in chrome.

Example [see here](http://www.hrgp.biz/Images/ajax-loader.gif)

Comment: That's a shame. If you want some help with this, let us know. We'll need to see an example, of course.

Comment: @ralph.m I have modify the question please have a look again.

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with your image, because not even Photoshop will open it. Try creating the image again.